# self hosted wcf service within windows service through error when adding service reference of wcf service in another web application

Tags: c#, wcf, utf-8

Error Detail :

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://localhost:8800/BCon/GetClient/$metadata'.
>
> The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:8800/BCon/GetClient'. The content type
>   application/json; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match
>   the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
>   method is implemented properly. The first 46 bytes of the response
>   were: '"lhPZ9uhtoYfYgRH38GzGDnEwk1ArWYN4526Mo9Uq31y9HM="'. If the
>   service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference again.

using this code create self hosted service in windows service

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Generat), new Uri("localhost:8800/BCon")); 
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior(); smb.HttpGetEnabled = true; 
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15; 
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb); 
host.Open();

[OperationContract(Name = "*")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/GetClient")]
```

Comment: Post your tried code. Also wsdl if possible

Comment: Operation contract and service contract I meant.

Comment: OperationContract

Comment: @Tusshar Post your code as part of the Question itself. Code posted in comments is not readable and is most likely to be ignored.

Comment: Web Application and WCF service both are running on the same computer?

Comment: yes running on same computer